# Как только через CSS выделить начиная от второго слова другим цветом?

Tags: html, css

Как **только через CSS** выделить начиная от второго слова другим цветом?

Также учесть что слово может быть одна буква, пример "О компании"

**Без изменения HTML**

Нужно первое слово сделать серым, все остальные слова красным:

```css
div {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>Самый простой текст</div>
<div>О компании</div>
```

Comment: Никак. Либо JS, либо разметка

Comment: Хочу уточнить, вам надо чтобы "Самый" был одного цвета, а всё остальное другим?

Comment: @DGDays, да, только первое слово

Comment: @DaemonHK, а как через js сделать? к примеру если задам класс блоку "title"

Comment: @SergeyMironov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существует масса проблем и ограничений даже с `::first-letter`, а уж `::first-word` и вовсе пока не существует в природе. Поэтому "pure CSS" тут не поможет - только JS.

Скриптами можно покрыть все потребности и хотелки, причём практически без простыней кода:

```js
let first = document.querySelector('.first');
first.innerHTML = first.innerHTML.replace(/(^ ?|<br> ?|[!?.] .*?)([\wа-яё]+)/gim, '$1<span class="hl">$2</span>');

let smart = document.querySelector('.smart');
smart.innerHTML = smart.innerHTML.replace(/(^ ?|<br> ?|[!?.] .*?)([\wа-яё]{3,})/gim, '$1<span class="hl">$2</span>');
```

```css
.hl { color: green; }
```

```html
<p class="first">Первое слово в данном предложении зеленого цвета! А второе уже чёрного.<br> Снова зелёное? Да, опять зелёное... Включая предлоги и коротенькие слова.</p>

<p class="smart">Первое слово в данном предложении зеленого цвета! А второе тоже зелёного.<br> Снова зелёное? Да, опять зелёное... Предлоги и короткие слова не захватываем.</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, жаль что на css пока такого нет, может в будущем добавят

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд лучшее решение.

```css
span:first-child {
  color: green;
}

span:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Первое</span>
  <span>слово в данном предложении зеленого цвета</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не то, нужно без изменения HTML, тоесть без разметки на теги

Comment: тогда `JS`. Больше ни как... `css`на это не способен

Comment: сейчас пытаюсь на js сделать, что то вариантов рабочих нигде нет

Comment: Но даже если реализовать через `js` придется первое слово обернуть тегом

Comment: да, на js только так, все правильно. У меня просто это динамический текст из базы. Но все равно на js вариантов нет, пробывал разные, ни один нерабочий

Comment: @SergeyMironov: на JS проще простого.

Comment: @UModeL, пришлите рабочий пример, у меня что то не выходит сделать