# Как добавить стили для текста?

Tags: html, css

Как можно застилизирывать текст без тега? Возможности добавить теги нет, так как разметка приходить с бэкенда?

```
<a href="#">Link Text</a>
"Some Text"
<a href="#">Link Text 2</a>
"Some Text 2"
```

Проблема разместить ссылки именно в таком порядке одна под одной и рядом текст что идет после ссылки без тега

```
Link Text Some Text
Link Text 2 Some Text 2
```

Comment: Ну,пришла разметка - пройдитесь по ней скриптом и стилизуйте, как Вам нужно.

Comment: я могу стилизирывать теги пробывал через a {display: block; float: left; clear: left; }
но не получаеться таким способом

Comment: @dev_jun https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1179151/265406

Comment: Куда вставляется эта разметка? Непосредственно в `body`? Или всё же в какой-то блок?  Минимальный пример.

Comment: @UModeL есть враппер и в него через dangerouslySetInnerHTML вставляю разметку

Comment: @dev_jun а зачем давать разметку с бекенда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-нить подобное мб?

```css
a::before{
  display:block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link Text</a>
Some Text
<a href="#">Link Text 2</a>
Some Text 2
```

Comment: Имеет право на жизнь. Возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант прописывать стили таким образом:

```
<a href="#" style="color:red;">Link Text</a>
"Some Text"
<a href="#" style="color:blue;">Link Text 2</a>
"Some Text 2"
```

То есть, мы передаём стиль в самом теге

Comment: проблема в расположении, я не могу ссылки разместить таким образом что бы текст после них вставал рядом а след. ссылка вставала под предыдущей

Comment: Ну, кроме тега `<br>` думаю вам ничего не поможет

Comment: нету возможности добавлять теги(

Comment: Либо надо как-то через JS перехватывать сообщение с бэкенда и приписывать этот тег или в самом бэкенде задать приписку тэга

Answer (score 0):

```js
let link = document.querySelector("a");
link.style.color = "red";
link.style.fontSize = "50px";
link.style.textDecoration = "underline";
```

```html
<a href="#">Link Text</a>
"Some Text"
```